# Memory error while slicing an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have object `d` connected to h5 dataset:

```
>>> data = d[:, :, 0].astype(np.float32)
>>> data.shape
(17201, 10801)
>>> data[data==-32768] = data[data>0].min()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Can I do some other slicing trick to avoid this error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the last line? The left hand side evaluates to an array of negative values -32768 while the right hand side is the smallest positive number in the array. The result thus will be an array of False values (the length will be the number of -32768 values in the array due to numpy broadcasting). Maybe there is another way of achieving your goal?

Comment: @David: I'm normalizing all values equal to -32768 to the minimal value of array greater then 0. If it's not obvious...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the `=` in the last line as a `==`. Your code is perfectly clear and should not need more explanation. My bad! Apparently, you're running into memory bounds. Can you evaluate the expression `data[data>0].min()` individually to determine the minimal number?

Comment: @theta I would really think you simply run out of memory... Maybe you are using a 32bit system (its a bit odd, since `data[data>0]` should not be too much larger then `data` (it might be somewhat larger because of temporary `data>0`. If your physical memory runs out, you could use `memmap`s + `tempfile` maybe.

Comment: How big is this datafile?  from my quick calculation, you're taking : `(17201*10801*32)/1024./1024./1000.` = `5.669799835205078Gb` of disk space just to hold this array section.

Comment: Also, just a word of caution here.  You're using floating point numbers (`np.float32`) but checking equality with an integer:  `data==-32768`.  This *can* work, but you need to be extremely careful due to inaccuracies with floating point arithmetic (which you may already be aware of -- In which case, think of this as a warning to others who might stumble upon this post).

Comment: @David: No, that's seems to be the problem. Anyhow I found a walk-through which I'll describe below

Comment: @seberg: Thanks for suggesting another ways, which I'll consider in future

Comment: @mgilson: h5 file is ~ 354MB. Data is signed short, but I needed for work in float. Solution was to use `np.short` while creating/slicing and then convert to `np.float`. It works! If someone wants to write an answer I'll accept, although it's just specific solution due to possibility of using simpler data type

Comment: @theta -- Feel free to write up the answer yourself when SO allows you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm writing answer myself, as there is acceptable solution, gained after @mgilson questioned data type.

If data allows, memory error can be avoided by using simpler data type while operating on array. Considering initial question this worked for me:

```
>>> data = d[:, :, 0].astype(np.short)
>>> data[data==-32768] = data[data>0].min()
>>> data = data.astype(np.float32)
```